# View#bringToFront not working on a button, only on a TextView in Android

Tags: android

My layout's XML is like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.hirewand.hudki.UploadResumeActivity"
android:background="#303030"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/actionBar"
    android:background="@color/black">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_menu"
        android:id="@+id/menu_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:onClick="moveMenu"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Your profile"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menu_button"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentPlaceholder"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_below="@id/actionBar">
</RelativeLayout>
<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
    android:text="UPLOAD RESUME"
    android:id="@+id/uploadButton"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg_rounded_corners"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="startSignupActivity"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_upload"
    android:drawablePadding="0dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This helps us find the perfect job for you"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/uploadButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm dynamically adding a fragment onto the place holder and animating it `onClick`

Here's the Java of my activity:

```
public class UploadResumeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_resume);

    //Hide the place holder, View.GONE implies it occupies no space
    RelativeLayout r1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragmentPlaceholder);
    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.fragmentPlaceholder, NavigationFragment.newInstance());
    ft.commit();
    r1.bringToFront();
    r1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void moveMenu(View view) {
    RelativeLayout r1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragmentPlaceholder);
    Animation slideIn,slideOut;
    slideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.enter_from_left);
    slideOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.exit_to_left);
    if(r1.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
    {
        r1.startAnimation(slideIn);
        r1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    else
    {
        r1.startAnimation(slideOut);
        r1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
}
```

This is how it looks: [image: Initially]

When i try open the fragment by clicking: [image: Upload button need to go behind]

I need the upload button to go behind the fragment. It works when I use `View.setZ()`. But my min API level is 14. Why doesn't `View.bringToFront()` work on the button?

Comment: Why not encase your last button and textview in another relative layout?

Comment: It seems brought to front alright. What did you expect? Otherwise why not move the button layout before the fragment placeholder in your layout, it would then by default be behind.

Comment: Thanks Steve, encasing my button and textview inside a relativelayout worked. :)

Comment: @JHH It was brought in front of the Textview, but not the Button, I wonder why..

Answer (score 0):

Steve Cs solution to encase my button and Textview inside a RelativeLayout worked.